# change background colour of ViewItem in RecyclerView.Adapter when another item clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am developing an android application for displaying list of items this is my code:

```
 public class CategoryAdapter extends 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterViewHolder> {

   private String[] categoriesData;
   private int numberOfCategories;
   private CategoriesListListener cOnClickListener;

   public interface CategoriesListListener {
    void onCategoryItemClick(int categoryItemIndex, int height, int width, 
         View view);
   }

   public CategoryAdapter(int numberOfCategories, CategoriesListListener listener) {
    this.numberOfCategories = numberOfCategories;
    cOnClickListener = listener;
   }

   public class CategoryAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener{


    public final TextView categoryTextView;
    public int adapterCounter;
    public CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;


    public void setCounter(int counter){
        adapterCounter = counter;
    }

    public void setCategoryAdapter(CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter){
        this.categoryAdapter = categoryAdapter;
    }

    public CategoryAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        categoryTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        int height = view.getHeight();
        int width = view.getWidth();
        cOnClickListener.onCategoryItemClick(clickedPosition, height, width, view);
        }
   }

  @Override
public CategoryAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.category_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    CategoryAdapterViewHolder categoryAdapterViewHolder = new CategoryAdapterViewHolder(view);
    categoryAdapterViewHolder.setCounter(getItemCount());
    categoryAdapterViewHolder.setCategoryAdapter(this);
    return categoryAdapterViewHolder;
     }

       @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapterViewHolder forecastAdapterViewHolder, int position) {
    String currentCategory = mCategoriesData[position];
    forecastAdapterViewHolder.categoryTextView.setText(currentCategory);
}

 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (null == mCategoriesData) return 0;
    return mCategoriesData.length;
}

  public void setCategoriesData(String[] categoriesData) {
     this.mCategoriesData = categoriesData;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
 }
```

when one Item is clicked the Listener's callback is called this Listener is implemented by a `Fragment` which passes an instance of itself to the above `CategoryAdapter`

```
  public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment implements 
     CategoryAdapter.CategoriesListListener {

    //some code here
    public interface OnCategoryClickListener{
        public void onCategoryClick(int position, String name, String 
             description,int height, int width, View view);
    }
    //some code here 
     @Override
    public void onCategoryItemClick(int categoryItemIndex,int height, int 
         width, View view) {
         cCallback.onCategoryClick(categoryItemIndex, 
                     categoriesName[categoryItemIndex],
         categories[categoryItemIndex], height, width, view);
     }

  }
```

Then the `Activity` implemented the `interface` inside the `Fragment`

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
               CategoriesFragment.OnCategoryClickListener{
               //some code here
                @Override
               public void onCategoryClick(int position, String name, String 
                   description, int height, int width, View view){

                           //some code here 
                     int finalRaduis = (int)Math.hypot(height/2, width/2);
                     Animator animator = 
        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, width/2, height/2, 0, 
                            finalRaduis);                
     view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),
                R.color.colorAccent2));
        animator.start();
       //some code here
    }
```

Then in the `ManActivity` after clicking the `view` I successfully changed the background color of the view, but the issue comes up when a new view is clicked in this case the previously clicked `view`'s background color doesn't turn to the default one.

**Question**
how should I modify my code so that when an new view is clicked the previously clicked one colour turns to default colour?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a member variable clickedPosition with deafult value to -1 in adapter class. In onBindViewHolder method you can check if clikedPostion == current postion then set the selection color other wise set to default color. call notififydataset changed method from onclick method to refresh the view. Add following code in adapter class

```
int clickedPosition = -1;
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapterViewHolder forecastAdapterViewHolder, int position) {
    .......
    .......
    if(clickedPosition == position) {
        // set selected color
    } else {
        // set default color
    }
}

public void onClick(View view){

    clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
    int height = view.getHeight();
    int width = view.getWidth();
    cOnClickListener.onCategoryItemClick(clickedPosition, height, width, view);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: that's right but how to get view from Adapter when only having the position is there any method implemented for this purpose?

Comment: You should set root layout/view in CategoryAdapterViewHolder and add click listener inside bind view holder method and remove on click from CategoryAdapterViewHolder class

Comment: could you please provide your solution in more details and modify my code, I am still confused how to get an view item form Adapter by its position

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution adding some code in **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    CategoriesFragment.OnCategoryClickListener{


//Define
int prevClickPos = -1;
View prevView = null;


//some code here
@Override
public void onCategoryClick(int position, String name, String
        description, int height, int width, View view){

    //some code here
    int finalRaduis = (int)Math.hypot(height/2, width/2);
    Animator animator =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, width/2, height/2, 0,
                    finalRaduis);
    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),
            R.color.colorAccent2));
    animator.start();


    //Change Background Default
    if(prevClickPos != -1 && prevClickPos != position) {
        prevView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),
                R.color.defaultColor));    //Apply Default color
    }
    prevClickPos = position;
    prevView = view;

    //some code here
}
```